# Multiply parts of cell array with factor in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, double, cell, cell-array

I want to multiply parts of a cell array in Matlab (see example below).

```
my_cell1 = {'a', 'b', 'c'; 'd', '1', '2'; 'e', '3', '4'};
% Looks like:
% a b c
% d 1 2
% e 3 4
my_cell2 = my_cell1;
my_cell2(2:3, 2:3) = num2cell(str2double(my_cell2(2:3, 2:3)) * 2); %Multiply the numbers by factor 2
my_cell3 = {'a', 'b', 'c'; 'd', '2', '4'; 'e', '6', '8'};
isequal(my_cell2, my_cell3) %False
```

Apparently, `my_cell2` is not equal to `my_cell3`. This seems to be the case because the numbers in `my_cell2` are now doubles and not strings/characters anymore. However, when I try to use them as strings, I get an error:

```
my_cell2 = my_cell1;
my_cell2(2:3, 2:3) = num2str(str2double(my_cell2(2:3, 2:3)) * 2); %Error: Conversion to cell from char is not possible.
```

How can I multiply `my_cell2` so that it becomes equal to `my_cell3` at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an intermediate step using [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply `str2num` to each of the cells in your (sub) cell array:

```matlab
my_cell1 = {'a', 'b', 'c'; 'd', '1', '2'; 'e', '3', '4'};

my_cell2 = my_cell1;
my_cell2(2:3, 2:3) = num2cell(str2double(my_cell2(2:3, 2:3)) * 2);
my_cell2(2:3, 2:3) = cellfun(@(x) num2str(x), my_cell2(2:3, 2:3), 'UniformOutput', false);

my_cell3 = {'a', 'b', 'c'; 'd', '2', '4'; 'e', '6', '8'};

isequal(my_cell2, my_cell3) % true
```

Since your initial "numerical" data is (also) represented as character arrays, you'll always need a proper conversion to numerical values. If your data would actually be numerical, this approach could be minimized:

```matlab
my_cell1 = {'a', 'b', 'c'; 'd', 1, 2; 'e', 3, 4};   % Note the difference here

my_cell2 = my_cell1;
my_cell2(2:3, 2:3) = cellfun(@(x) 2*x, my_cell2(2:3, 2:3), 'UniformOutput', false);

my_cell3 = {'a', 'b', 'c'; 'd', 2, 4; 'e', 6, 8};   % Note the difference here

isequal(my_cell2, my_cell3) % true
```

I couldn't find a way to directly access and manipulate the values of the cell array in the corresponding range via `my_cell2{2:3, 2:3}`. Maybe, someone else has an idea on that.

Hope that helps!

---

Disclaimer: Tested with Octave 5.1.0, but also works in MATLAB Online.